# React native Android. Установить цвет панели приложения в режиме recent apps

Tags: android, react-native

Как настроить цвет "заголовка" приложения в режиме "recent apps". На примере картинки, у chrome - серый, у vivino - красный.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй изменять цвета, как советуют [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33595629/5812238)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел https://stackoverflow.com/a/45093166/1778019

1.Создать colors.xml в android/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Change the color value for your need -->
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

2.Отредактировать styles.xml в android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

3. Больше информации https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html